# Is an Identity Map sufficient for a caching mechanism?

Tags: php, caching, datamapper

I have just implemented a simple IdentityMap in my DataMappers, ran a little test retrieving some objects which in turn depend on other objects so a few queries needed to do be. I was amazed to find that with the IdentityMap implemented it had cut the number of database queries down to a third of the previous amount.

Is an IdentityMap sufficient for caching or should you go a step further?

Comment: Sufficient for what? This is impossible to answer without knowing what your requirements are. Obviously an identity map isn't enough for facebook, but it could be for your blog.

Answer (score 0):

The main purpose of an identity map in a mapping system is not caching.
The map keeps one object per identity to avoid multiple instances so only one object exists.

However, an identity map also reduces the number of queries and thus act as a cache in that way.